# Google chrome and chromium black window

Tags: centos, chrome

When I update my google chrome or chromium to a version that is higher than 38 The window of the browser gets **black** functional square. It's all black even the top bar. I basically can't see anything just black. When I downgrade to version 38 or previous version, It runs correctly. The machine has centos 6.6 `3.10.56-11.el6.centos.alt.x86_64`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Black Chrome windows are often, but not always, a symptom of a version mismatch between the X11 video driver and the kernel video driver. I've found that, amongst the programs I use regularly, Chrome was by far the most sensitive to such mismatches. Such a mismatch usually happens after doing a partial system upgrade. Finishing the upgrade and rebooting (to get the new kernel driver) solves the problem, if a driver mismatch was the cause.

Comment: partial system upgrade? you mean upgrading to centos 7?

Comment: @hegazy No, any upgrade, such as a security upgrade, for example if both the kernel driver and the X driver have been updated and you've restarted the X server but not rebooted.

Comment: The system is already up-to-date. There is no updates available and nothing have changed.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL/CentOS 6 is not supported by Chrome since v28. It could be all sorts of problems.

You could try alternative install scripts, like the one from

http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/

to be sure everything is in place, but on the long run I don't think you will get happier.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the black window issue.